# Invoking a function on a keypress in vim editor compiled with python

Tags: vim-plugin

I'm looking for a code to invoke a plugin when a key is pressed in VIM editor in Linux terminal.The plugin has to replace automatically an image path given in the file opened in Vim with that image converted into ascii. Please help me in adding key press so that the plugin works in an automated fashion???

Answer (score 0):

The title of your question is

> **Invoking a function on a keypress in vim editor compiled with python**

and I can answer that:
you can map key presses to functions using

```
:map Keycombo :Command^M
```

see vim's builting help `:help map`.

---

However, what you're asking for in the text is us to write you a complex vim script that possibly uses an external program to convert that image to ASCII art, and then to map it to a keybinding. Obviously, the key binding is the easiest part. Since we're not your paid contractors, we won't write code for you that you haven't even tried to write yourself.